# Add horizontal line to the Gmail body using Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, horizontal-line

I am working with data from a Google Spreadsheets obtained from a Google Forms and I want to send an email of response to a customer. That's why I created a Google Script.

**Is it possible to add an horizontal line/rule to the Gmail body using `GmailApp.sendEmail(...)`?** Something like:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail('example@gmail.com', 'Title', 'Hello.\n\n[CommandForHR]');
```

I know I can use `'---------'` to simulate the bar, but I am curious if there exists such command in Google Script.

### Searchs

I have searched on the [Google Developers webpage](https://developers.google.com/s/results/apps-script/s/results/?q=horizontal%20rule%20element) but the results are for Google Docs, not Gmail App.

From above, [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/horizontal-rule) seems to be the command I am looking for, but I don't know how to implement it inside the parameters of `GmailApp.sendEmail(...)`.

Comment: To use the HTML body instead of the text body is included in your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike sorry but I don't understand your question. I want to respect the syntax of how `sendEmail` parameters were designed. So I will go for "text body" if I got it right.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying of `I want to respect the syntax of how sendEmail parameters were designed. So I will go for "text body" if I got it right.`, I understood that you are required to achieve your goal using the text body instead of the HTML body. I thought that if the HTML body can be used, the horizontal line can be used. By the way, Class HorizontalRule in your question is used for Document service. In this case, it cannot be used for GmailApp.

Comment: @Tanaike you didn't phrased it bad! I am not programmer :-). If you can put examples of "text body" and "HTML body" I will be grateful. However, you are right about Class HorizontalRule, it is for Google Docs. Is there any similar command for GMail services in the scope of a Google Script?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `If you can put examples of "text body" and "HTML body" I will be grateful.`, in the case of HTML, I thought that `<hr>` can be used. About `Is there any similar command for Google Forms services?`, do you want to change your question? I couldn't understand about this your new question? I apologize for this.

Comment: If you can use the HTML body, you can use the sample script of `GmailApp.sendEmail("mail address", "sample subject", "sample text body", {htmlBody: "sample text 1<br><hr>sample text 2"});`. You can also test this script.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you it worked!! I have two questions that came to my mind: 1) Since you have found the `htmlBody` I don't need anymore the 3rd parameter of `sendEmail` so: For a correct syntax do we have to write `""` as 3rd parameter? 2) Are there any cons when using `htmlBody`, like security issues, browser incompatibilities and so on? You can answer these questions by posting an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your question was resolved. About your 2nd question of `Since you have found the htmlBody I don't need anymore the 3rd parameter of sendEmail so: For a correct syntax do we have to write "" as 3rd parameter?`, you can use `GmailApp.sendEmail("mail address", "sample subject", "", {htmlBody: "sample text 1<br><hr>sample text 2"});` and/or `MailApp.sendEmail({to: "mail address", subject: "sample subject", htmlBody: "sample text 1<br><hr>sample text 2"});`.

Comment: @Tanaike forget about the 3rd question because it is answered in [this Google Developers input](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#advanced-parameters), if you want to post an answer I will be grateful

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I answered for your 2 questions. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q1: Is it possible to add an horizontal line/rule to the Gmail body using GmailApp.sendEmail(...)?

A1: In this case, when the HTML body is used, the horizontal line can be put using `<hr>`. The sample script is as follows.

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("mail address", "sample subject", "sample text body", {htmlBody: "sample text 1<br><hr>sample text 2"});
```

> Q2: Since you have found the htmlBody I don't need anymore the 3rd parameter of sendEmail so: For a correct syntax do we have to write "" as 3rd parameter?

A2: If you doesn't use the text body, you can also modify above script as follows.

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("mail address", "sample subject", "", {htmlBody: "sample text 1<br><hr>sample text 2"});
```

or, you can also use `MailApp.sendEmail()` as follows.

```
MailApp.sendEmail({to: "mail address", subject: "sample subject", htmlBody: "sample text 1<br><hr>sample text 2"});
```

#### References:

- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options) of Class GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)
- [sendEmail(message) of Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage)